# Jekyll-bootstrap how does mark down for external links work?

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I am currently writing this in my post.md

`Intro to [links](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/)`

Then when I am clicking this link once the post has been published the link I am sent to is:

`http://example.github.io/post-name/jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/`

Can anyone help?

Comment: For regular Markdown your code looks fine. Does [this note](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/#absolute_permalinks) about enabling absolute permalinks help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gotcha. I had recently migrated from from [Maruku to kramdown](http://help.github.com/articles/migrating-your-pages-site-from-maruku), which [handles urls differently](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#links-and-images). You need to define
`[setid]: http://www.example.com` (don't forget the `http://`)

Then use `[setid]` in place of  the link.